# Bockstein Spectral Sequence (Why is this a direct sum)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-topology, spectral-sequences

[image]

(from McCleary's User guide pg 459).

I am curious why is $pH_n(X)+\ker p^r$ a direct sum? (Or is it?)

I tried to reason that $\ker p^r$ is equal to $\text{Im}\ \partial:H_{n+1}(X;\mathbb{F}_p)\to H_n(X)$, so those elements in $\ker p^r$ "come from" $H_{n+1}(X;\mathbb{F_p})$ where they are already reduced mod p, so the only way an element $u$ in $\ker p^r$ can be in $pH_n(X)$ (a multiple of $p$) is when $u$ is the zero element.

Is that correct reasoning?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a direct sum. Consider for example when $r=1$ and we have $H_n(X)=\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$. Then $p\cdot H_n(X)=\ker(H_n(X)\xrightarrow{\times p}H_n(X))$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just one more question, why do they say "Notice that $B_n^{r+1}=\{0\}$"? How do they know that $B_n^{r+1}=\{0\}$, or is it some assumption?

Comment: I think you might be just misreading that. The full sentence is the implication: If $B^{r+1}_n=0$ then $H_n(X)=p\cdot H_n(X)+\ker(p^r)$.

Comment: Thanks. Pardon my naive question, but how is that useful? As in, why do we even consider what happens if $B_n^{r+1}=\{0\}$?

Comment: Glancing quickly at the proof, it doesn't seem like an integral statement. If you think in terms of proposition 10.4, it can give some insight into what is going on under the spectral sequence magic.